# How to store wrong predictions during evaluation on the CNN

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

During evaluation, I want to store unique ids that are wrongly predicted to do some more processing.
It is a multiclass prediction problem

Here is the code during the evaluation:

```py
 outputs = model(imgs)
 loss = criterion(outputs, targets)  # Prediction error

 val_loss += loss.item()
 predicted = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
 t_predicted +=predicted.cpu().tolist()

 total += targets.size(0)
 good_answers = (predicted == targets)
 correct += good_answers.sum().item()
```

Knowing that `ids` is a list of the ids of the images,  When I try to get the ids that are wrong:

```py
wrong_ids += ids[~(good_answers.to('cpu'))]
```

I get this error:

```
add(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor
```

Answer (score 2):

The question contained a `tensorflow` tag, so I was preparing an answer. After completing my write up, I've found that this tag is removed. However, I believe my answer can give insight into this **general question** of whether they're using `tf` or `pytorch`.

---

#### Data

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# train set / data 
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255

# validation set / data 
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

# train set / target 
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
# validation set / target 
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)
```

#### Train

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# declare input shape 
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,3))
# Block 1
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, activation="relu")(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
# Now that we apply global max pooling.
gap = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
# Finally, we add a classification layer.
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(gap)
# bind all
func_model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)

print('\nFunctional API')
func_model.compile(
          metrics=['accuracy'],
          loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
          )

func_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

#### Error Prediction

```
# Predict the values from the validation dataset
y_pred = func_model.predict(x_test)
# Convert predictions classes to one hot vectors 
y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1) 
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

# Errors are difference between predicted labels and true labels
errors = (y_pred_classes - y_test != 0)

y_pred_classes_errors = y_pred_classes[errors]
y_pred_errors = y_pred[errors]
y_true_errors = y_test[errors]
x_test_errors = x_test[errors]

# Probabilities of the wrong predicted numbers
y_pred_errors_prob = np.max(y_pred_errors, axis = 1)

# Predicted probabilities of the true values in the error set
true_prob_errors = np.diagonal(np.take(y_pred_errors, y_true_errors, axis=1))

# Difference between the probability of the predicted label and the true label
delta_pred_true_errors = y_pred_errors_prob - true_prob_errors

# Sorted list of the delta prob errors
sorted_dela_errors = np.argsort(delta_pred_true_errors)

# Top 6 errors 
most_important_errors = sorted_dela_errors[-6:]
```

**Display**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_errors(errors_index,img_errors,pred_errors, obs_errors):
    """ This function shows 6 images with their predicted and real labels"""
    n = 0
    nrows = 2
    ncols = 3
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,sharex=True,sharey=True)
    for row in range(nrows):
        for col in range(ncols):
            error = errors_index[n]
            ax[row,col].imshow((img_errors[error]).reshape((32,32,3)))
            ax[row,col].set_title("Predicted label :{}\nTrue label :{}".format(pred_errors[error],obs_errors[error]))
            n += 1

# Show the top 6 errors
display_errors(most_important_errors, x_test_errors, y_pred_classes_errors, y_true_errors)
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks, however as Im new to this I didnt figure out how to use ur answer to get my code to store none correct values(knowing that the model is doing good in predicting labels)
It's only about the last line in my question

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to declare empty list and then to fill them with the predictions

```py
    # TO GET ONLY THE WRONGLY LABELED ITEMS
    wrong_ids.append(ids[~(predicted == targets ).to('cpu')])
     
    # TO ALSO STORE ALL TESTED LABELS PREDICTED AND TARGETS IN SEPARATE LIST
    tested_labels.append(ids.to('cpu'))
    pred_labels.append(predicted.to('cpu'))
    true_labels.append(targets.to('cpu'))
```

then after that to convert the resulting list of tensors to one list:

```py
wrongs =[]
for i,j in enumerate(wrong_ids):
    for k,l in enumerate(j):
        wrongs.append(l.item())

# and so on for the other lists of tensors
```

To show all tested labels with the predictions and the true labels:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids,
                   'predicted': pred_label,
                   'true_label': true_label})
print(df)
```